# How to convert the factor value?

Tags: r

```
>str(T$gender)
 Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 ...
```

The value gender in Data T looks like this. There is no match between the factor level and the factor value . So I just want to convert the value 2 to 1 , and 1 to 0.

I mean I want that the R programming return this. Factor w/2 levels "0","1" : 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 ....)

I tried this way.

```
T<-transform(T,gender=ifelse(gender==1,0,1))
str(T$gender)
T$gender<-as.factor(T$gender)
```

But it doesn't change the value. Could someone help me?

Comment: Factors are internally coded as integers starting with 1 to the number of levels. The first level is 1, the second level 2, etc. The labels indicate how each level is printed, so in your case the first level is labeled `"0"`, your second level is labeled `"1"`. What you are asking for is a fundamental change to how factors are coded and stored---it would require rewriting pieces of R, recompiling the language, and it would probably break many, many other functions and packages.

Comment: So, the question is *why* do you want to do this? What problem do you have that you think this is the solution? Could you just convert it to an integer? Is conversion necessary at all? Do note that if you `print(T$gender)` or just look at `T$gender`, it will print the way you request.

Comment: Also, avoid using `T` as a variable name - save `T` for `TRUE`.

Comment: I want to change all of the value to 0-1 in dataframe T. So It can works with logistic regression. I hope the result will come out like this . ( Factor w/2 levels "0","1" : 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 ....). But I can't , even I tried to the comments that others recommends.

Comment: Yes, I understand that your short-term goal is *"Factor w/2 levels "0","1" : 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0"*. Please read my first comment carefully: **this goal is essentially impossible. You would need to re-write the R language to make it happen**. Logistic regression (and OLS regression, and most any other modeling function in R) knows how to deal with `factors` as they are currently implemented - the `glm` function it will dummy codes factors as columns with values 0 and 1 automatically. You can use logistic regression just fine on your current data, so your goal is pointless.

Comment: Oh I got it. Now I understand what you mean. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
T$gender <- as.factor(ifelse(as.numeric(as.character(T$gender)) == 2, 1, 0))
```

Comment: I've tried that you recommends , but It doesn't work. The results shows >> Factor w/ 1 level "0": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ... like this. It changes all values.

Answer (score -1):

I hope this will help :

Input :

```
a<-as.factor(c(1,2,1,2,1,2))
b<-NULL
for(i in 1:length(a)){
  if(a[i]==1){
    b[i]=1}
  else{b[i]=0}
}
b<-as.factor(b)
str(b)
```

Output :

```
Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 2 1 2 1
```

Here output after " : " represents the level number which is matching to index of b 
level 1 is 0, and level 2 is 1
and output of b is :

> [1] 1 0 1 0 1 0
>
> Levels: 0 1

since first element of b is 1 which matches with level 2 , str(b) gives you ouput mentioned above.

[r](/questions/tagged/r) [loops](/questions/tagged/loops)